# Cache Manifest Absolute URL Conflict with htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, caching, manifest

**The situation:**

1. Made htaccess remove file extension so when I access `www.example.com/index.html` it will link to `www.example.com/index/`
2. Created a cache manifest (works fine so we can rule out problems with its structure)

**The problem:**

- Even since I made htaccess change links, cache manifest no longer works for index.html
- example:

> ```
> CACHE MANIFEST
> index.html
> ```

and in console I would get `cache manifest resource fetch failed (-1)`.

this is probably because when the browser tries to access `www.example.com/index.html` it would get redirected to `www.example.com/index/` and it is confused?

Is there any way to get it to cache the link directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that all files that are to be stored in the cache need to be **explicitly stated**, or in other words, the full absolute URL has to be written or a full relative URL must be written in order for the cache to download the file.

aka

```
index.html 
blablah.js 
hello/world.png
```

all should work but

```
index/ 
bippitybop/js/ 
goodbye_cruel/world/*
```

won't work.

Let me know if this helps, if this question is even still active.